# Connecting to smtp server windows C++

Tags: c++, sockets, smtp, connect

I'm trying to create a client manager. I'have read some information about sockets. I'm doing my first steps and I've got my first problem.

This is my code:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <cstdio>
     #include <winsock2.h>
     #include <windows.h>
     #pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

     using namespace std;
     const int VERSION_MAJOR = 1;
     const int VERSION_MINOR = 1;

     int main()
     {
        WSADATA WSData;
        SOCKET sock;
        struct sockaddr_in addr;

        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(VERSION_MAJOR, VERSION_MINOR), &WSData)

        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(25); // или любой другой порт...
        hostent *server_adress = gethostbyname("smtp.gmail.com");
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *)server_adress->h_addr_list[0]);   
        int con = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
        cout << "connect status " << con << '\n';

       return 0;
    }
```

connect() returns -1

why i can't connect? Where is mistake?

Please, help me

Comment: What happens if you change sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); to sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); ?

Comment: @Joseph Pla Nothing happens. connect() still returns -1(((

Comment: Very weird, I'm getting 0 on my machine. Make sure you check your internet connectivity.

Comment: Unless you are on stack overflow on the same computer :P

Comment: @Joseph Pla Internet connectivity is normal. I tried on other laptop and got the same problem(((

Comment: Have you checked to see if WSA started up properly. Are you sure its a problem with the connect itself? Make sure you catch errors before the connect.

Comment: @Joseph Pla Finally, solved))) Port 25 blocked. Maybe by local provider(as anti-spamming measure). I changed port and connected to server)) Thanks a lot for your help!)))

Comment: alright, good to hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

You do not specify a protocol. You should change it to

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

This is the kind of protocol you are going to want to establish with something such as a mailing service.